# Sitecore Dictionary Items

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc, sitecore8.1

In the earlier versions of Sitecore there were an issue with dictionary items, if we have a CDs environment, sometimes the Dictionary.dat file may not get updated on CDs server.

1) is this issue still exist with Sitecore 8 ?

2) if yes, what is the best approach to implement custom dictionary items for my website ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. I have this issue on Sitecore 8.1 Initial Release.
2. To fix it you need to add on publish:end and publish:end:remote event a new handler.
   This is the class :

   ```
   public class DictionaryCacheClearer
   {
   /// <summary>
   /// Clears the whole dictionary domain cache.
   /// </summary>
   /// <param name="sender">The sender.</param>
   /// <param name="args">The <see cref="EventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
   public void ClearCache(object sender, EventArgs args)
   {
       Translate.ResetCache();
       Log.Info("Dictionary cleared", this);
   }
   }
   ```

   On publish:end and publish:end:remote events you will have:

   ```
   <event name="publish:end:remote">
    <handler type="Sitecore.Publishing.HtmlCacheClearer, Sitecore.Kernel" method="ClearCache">
      <sites hint="list">
       <site s="1">YourSite</site>
      </sites>
     </handler>
    <handler type="YourNameSpace.DictionaryCacheClearer, YourAssembly" method="ClearCache" />
   </event>

   <event name="publish:end">
   <handler type="Sitecore.Publishing.HtmlCacheClearer, Sitecore.Kernel" method="ClearCache">
     <sites hint="list">
       <site s="1">YourSite</site>
     </sites>
   </handler>
   <handler type="YourNameSpace.DictionaryCacheClearer, YourAssembly" method="ClearCache" />
   </event>
   ```

   Other fix you find it here: https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/8/t/173