# Sitecore dictionary item fallback fails when removing version

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching, sitecore, sitecore8

We are running sitecore 8.1 and have a problem with item fallback when removing a dictionary item in some language version.

We have fallback from "fr-FR" to "en". If i a dictionary item is created in "en" language, then "fr-FR" language shows the correct value (the "en" phrase value). If we add a version for "fr-FR" the "fr-FR" value is returned as expected. When removing the "fr-FR" version the fallback never works until making a change to the "en" version (not enough just saving). 
We are retrieving the value using this:

```
 @Translate.TextByLanguage("Root/Header/Search/Search Button")
```

If we instead are loading the sitecore dictionary item like this:

```
item = Html.Sitecore().CurrentItem.Database.Items.GetItem("/sitecore/system/Dictionary/Foss/Header/Search/Search Button")

 @item["phrase"]
```

Then everything is working as expected. App recycle and deleting dictionary.dat is not fixing this. But it must be some kind of dictionary cache issue.

Comment: can you try this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36233165/sitecore-dictionary-items